# How can I configure multiple goals in Google Analytics to work correctly?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I'm not sure how to ask this question correctly in the title, but essentially I set up 2 goals in Google Analytics. One goal is to just track account creations and the other goal is to track the first time a user creates a "module".

Gooogle Analytics seems to attribute both goals to the the account creation goal.

Here is a screenshot of the setup for Goal 1 (account creation).

[Google Analytics - Goal 1 Setup (Account Creation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLUpt.png)

Here is a screenshot from Google Analytics showing Goal 2 setup.

[Google Analytics - Goal 2 Setup (First Module Creation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y7va.png)

I tested all of the regular expressions in Google Analytics and they show the correct pages, so it should work.

Comment: The funnel settings affect visualisation only. So two goals with the same destination are effectively the same goal regardless of funnel settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics account setup and is not programing related. may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Eike, that's interesting. Thank you. I thought it was related to my regular expressions not being correct. I did validate each expression in GA, but thought maybe there's something funky going on.

Comment: I think I got it figured out. This is how I changed and updated the regular expression: http://imgur.com/a/T79YQ